# How can I use autoincrement without the help of database in php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form which user submits and is sent directly to the e-mail. The problem is that I'm not storing these values in database and directly mailing them. It is like a complaint registering system. What I want to do is that when the user submits a complaint and is redirected to success page, a complaint number is generated which should be obviously incremental by 1 for the next submission. Also there is no separate user account as anyone visiting the website can submit complaints. I tried using a field option as unique id but it didn't really work.
The html form is,

```
    <form method="post" action="handler.php">

    <div>
        <label for="first_name"><span class="labelname"><strong>First Name:</strong></span></label> 
        <input type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" class="required" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="last_name"><span class="labelname"><strong>Last Name:</strong></span></label> 
        <input type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" class="required" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="telephone"><span class="labelname"><strong>Telephone Number:</strong></span></label> 
        <input type="text" maxlength="20" size="50" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="" class="required" />
    </div>


    <div>
        <label for="email"><span class="labelname"><strong>E-mail: (Optional)</strong></span></label> 
        <input type="email" maxlength="30" size="50" name="email" id="email" value="" class="" />
    </div>



    <div>
        <label for="com_type"><span class="labelname"><strong>Complaint Type:</strong></span></label>   
        <select name="com_type" id="com_type" class="required">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="Electrician">Electrician</option>
         <option value="Plumber">Plumber</option>
         <option value="Mason">Mason</option>
         <option value="Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="flat_no"><span class="labelname"><strong>Flat No.:</strong></span></label> 
        <input type="text" maxlength="10" size="50" name="flat_no" id="flat_no" value="" class="required" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="block_no"><span class="labelname"><strong>Block Number:</strong></span></label>   
        <select name="block_no" id="block_no" class="required">
         <option value=""> </option>
         <option value="A-1">A-1</option>
         <option value="A-2">A-2</option>
         <option value="A-3">A-3</option>
         <option value="A-4">A-4</option>
         <option value="A-5">A-5</option>
         <option value="A-6">A-6</option>
         <option value="A-7">A-7</option>
         <option value="B-1">B-1</option>
         <option value="B-2">B-2</option>
         <option value="B-3">B-3</option>
         <option value="B-4">B-4</option>
         <option value="C-1">C-1</option>
         <option value="C-2">C-2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="message"><span class="labelname"><strong>Describe your problem:</strong></span></label>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="2000" name="message" id="message" class="required"></textarea>
    </div>

       <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email">Submit Complaint</button> <button class="reset" type="reset">Reset</button>
```

php code,

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
die("Error. You need to submit the form.");
}
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$com_type = $_POST['com_type'];
$flat_no = $_POST['flat_no'];
$block_no = $_POST['block_no'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_from = $visitor_email;
$email_subject = "New Complaint";
$email_body = "message\n\n". "First Name: $first_name\n\n". 
"Last Name:  $last_name\n\n".
"Telephone: $telephone\n\n". "Complaint Type: $com_type\n\n". 
"Flat No.: $flat_no\n\n". "Block No.: $block_no\n\n". 
"Complaint: $message";

$to = "my email.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

try{
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//success, redirect to thank

header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/thank.php'); 
} catch(Exception $e){
//problem, redirect to fail
header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/fail.php'); 
}       
?>
```

I just want a complaint number on the successful submission page and the complaint number should also go in the mail also with other details. Can I do it without using the database. Please help.

Comment: If you don't want to use database for this, create a file where you will be keeping just the number of previous complaint, and when success - increment that number and save it back.

Comment: Why do you not want to use database?

Comment: @dj aqeel it's one of the requirement to not use database, this is the main reason i'm stuck in this situation.

Comment: @Gaurav Check out my solution, and see if it works for you. Although it is performance intensive, as dj aqeel says.

Comment: @Gaurav, if not using the database is a requirement then what is the purpose of auto-incremented id?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i'am using and testing your solution, but i guess i'll have to use the database for this

Comment: @djaqeel, for me everything is working with using database but as a requirement of my client I can't use database. I know that auto-increment id isn't really helping here, I just wanted to know if there is a solution for my problem

Comment: @Gaurav OKay great...

Comment: @Gaurav I mean, if the complaint id is not to be saved anywhere then what is the purpose of generating it? The purpose of ids is that they can be used for future reference. But in this case complaint id is not to be saved anywhere(as you told as required), then why bother to generate it even?

Comment: For that matter you can use current time long value as complaint id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the numbers stored as a primary key, then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`;
```

Or if you have the `auto_increment` or `PRIMARY KEY` set, you can use:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table`;
```

And then add `+ 1` to the result and insert it as new. If you aren't using a database, then use a flat file named `count.txt` for it and put in the current number and increment:

```
<?php
  $count = file_get_contents("count.txt");
  $count++;
  file_put_contents("count.txt", $count);
?>
```

But this option is not so good. So please use a mechanism to lock the file while updating the count.

Comment: Perhaps you can use file locking in order to prevent a wrong counter value in case of concurrent requests.

Comment: @djaqeel Updated the answer... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ur solution worked for me but since its not very safe, i'm using database but i accept ur answer as it helped for the time being.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav, please tell me what's not very safe in this?